# Не отображается изображение в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap, parent

Когда я хочу загрузить изображения в окно *PyQt5*,
у меня не загружается!

Вот код:

**oilukla.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wind = QWidget()

names = {}
lsprite_base = {}

class oilwin():
    def __init__(self, res_x, res_y, title, resiz, icon) -> None:
        self.res_x = res_x
        self.res_y = res_y
        self.title = title
        self.resize = resiz
        self.icon = icon

    def draw_win(self):
        global app, wind
        if self.icon != None:
            wind.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.icon))

        if self.title != '':
            wind.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        elif self.title == '':
            wind.setWindowTitle('oilukla window')

        if self.resize == True:
            wind.setFixedSize(self.res_x, self.res_y)

        wind.resize(self.res_x, self.res_y)

    def resize_win(self, nres_x, nres_y):
        global wind
        if self.resize == False:
            wind.resize(nres_x, nres_y)
        elif self.resize == True:
            wind.setFixedSize(nres_x, nres_y)

    def rename_win(self, ntitle):
        global wind
        wind.setWindowTitle(ntitle)

    def ena_window(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec())

    def draw_obj(self):
        wind.show()


class oilentity():
    def __init__(self, name, sprite, res_x, res_y) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.res_x = res_x
        self.res_y = res_y

        globals()['lsprite'] = self.sprite
        globals()['res_x'] = self.res_x
        globals()['res_y'] = self.res_y

    def add_object(self):
        main_dict = {}
        main_dict = dict({'sprite':lsprite, 'res_x':res_x, 'res_y':res_y})

        with open(self.name + '.data', 'wb') as d_file:
            d_file.write(str(main_dict).encode('utf-8'))

        globals()['llabel'] = QLabel()

        tsprite = QPixmap(lsprite)

        llabel.setPixmap(tsprite)
        llabel.resize(16, 16)

        print(llabel)
```

**main.py**

```
from oilukla.oilukla import *

res_x = 640
res_y = 480
title = 'Oilukla Window Render Example'
resizable = True
icon = 'sprites/hero.png'

win = oilwin(res_x, res_y, title, resizable, icon)
win.draw_win()

my_object = oilentity('my_object', icon, 16,16)
my_object.add_object()

win.draw_obj()
win.ena_window()
```

Вот изображение того что я получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад, если подскажете или попробуете решить проблему.

*Python 3.9.6*

*Windows 10 LTSC x64*

Comment: I've gotta forget to tell, its some prototype of my 2d game engine!

Comment: ENEM, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я первый раз вижу такое странное написание кода, но я ничего не менял. Если вам надо будут предложения по улучшению кода - зададите новый вопрос.

Чтобы изображения появилось в окне PyQt5, вам при создании объекта `QLabel`, надо задать родителя:

```
globals()['llabel'] = QLabel(globals()['wind'])
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from oilukla.oilukla import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wind = QWidget()

names = {}
lsprite_base = {}


class oilentity():
    def __init__(self, name, sprite, res_x, res_y) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.res_x = res_x
        self.res_y = res_y

        globals()['lsprite'] = self.sprite
        globals()['res_x'] = self.res_x
        globals()['res_y'] = self.res_y

    def add_object(self):
        main_dict = {}
        main_dict = dict({'sprite':lsprite, 'res_x':res_x, 'res_y':res_y})
        
        with open(self.name + '.data', 'wb') as d_file:
            d_file.write(str(main_dict).encode('utf-8'))

# 1 как отдельное окно
#        globals()['llabel'] = QLabel(flags=Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

# 2 QLabel в главном окне 'wind'      
        globals()['llabel'] = QLabel(globals()['wind'])

#                                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  # <---- +++
        tsprite = QPixmap(lsprite).scaled(70, 70)


        llabel.setPixmap(tsprite)
#        llabel.resize(16, 16)

# 1 как отдельное окно
#        llabel.show()          # +++

        print(llabel)


class oilwin():
    def __init__(self, res_x, res_y, title, resiz, icon) -> None:
        self.res_x = res_x
        self.res_y = res_y
        self.title = title
        self.resize = resiz
        self.icon = icon

    def draw_win(self):
        global app, wind
        if self.icon != None:
            wind.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.icon))

        if self.title != '':
            wind.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        elif self.title == '':
            wind.setWindowTitle('oilukla window')

        if self.resize == True:
            wind.setFixedSize(self.res_x, self.res_y)

        wind.resize(self.res_x, self.res_y)

    def resize_win(self, nres_x, nres_y):
        global wind
        if self.resize == False:
            wind.resize(nres_x, nres_y)
        elif self.resize == True:
            wind.setFixedSize(nres_x, nres_y)

    def rename_win(self, ntitle):
        global wind
        wind.setWindowTitle(ntitle)

    def ena_window(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec())

    def draw_obj(self):
        wind.show()        



res_x = 640
res_y = 480
title = 'Oilukla Window Render Example'
resizable = True
icon = 'Ok.png'    # 'sprites/hero.png'

win = oilwin(res_x, res_y, title, resizable, icon)
win.draw_win()

my_object = oilentity('my_object', icon, 16, 16)
my_object.add_object()

win.draw_obj()
win.ena_window()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам разобрался в своем (плохом) коде, и забыл в QLabel записать значения wind, и так-же очистил свой код от лишнего! Спасибо!